# Is selecting from the same server but different database slower than the same database?

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

I am thinking about 2 possibilities that I want to use in my project. So there are 2 projects, with different databases each. So Project P1, has Database D1, and Table T1. Project P2, has Database D2.

For Project P2, I need to select the data at Table T1 quite often. Is it better to create a replicate of T1 inside Database D2 (name it T2), and do `SELECT * from T2` instead of doing `SELECT * FROM [D1].[T1]` ?

The 2 databases D1 and D2 are in the same server.

Comment: have you already did your testing?

Comment: As a side note: you can't parameterise database names when referring to tables by db.schema.tablename so may end up with many references to change if the name of database 2 changes for any reason. Instead of direct references everywhere I suggest creating views in a separate schema in database 1 of the form `CREATE VIEW external.sometable AS SELECT * FROM database2.schema.sometable` and referring to those in other code instead. That way you can update database names with a lot less work.

Comment: @EdgarAllanBayron For some reason, I did not notice any difference when selecting over 400K records for same or different server. But I'm looking to any other insight that I might have missed.

Comment: @DavidSpillett Yes, I'm planning to use VIEW for this. Thanks for your info.

Answer (score 3):

To add a bit to TomTom's comment: The optimizer has full access to meta-data etc regardless of whether the data is in one database or several databases. And the optimizer or execution engine is on constrained to one database. As long at it is in the same instance! If you talk about cross-instance queries (using linked servers, for instance), then you will definitely hurt!

Comment: Could you make this a "bit more" of an answer? It's close - maybe some references and/or extra content?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it better to create a replicate of T1 inside Database D2

No. Besides using double disc scpace, you also use couble memory if you access identical data from 2 copies of a table. And as memory is what is the most efficient buffer, you at least theoretically reduce system effectiveness. Theoeretically because a proper server may just not care - if you have half a terabyte ram and the duplicate table is 100kb then all impact is purely theoretical.